# Error encoding UTF-8 in netbeans-13 with jdk 1.8

Tags: netbeans, utf-8, internationalization

How can I fix this problem with netbeans13 in window10? I'm using JDK 1.8 also JRE I am learning web applications with java. The problem start is when I type ư (Vietnamese character) into the editor, it starts to convert in to ?. How can I fix this?

I tried to add  `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to netbeans.conf, restart Netbeans, install again and again, but it seem not working.

```
<<script language = "JavaScript">
var Ten, Tuoi;      // Khai bao 2 bien de luu ten va tuoi
Ten  = prompt("Bạn hãy nhập vào tên ", "");
Tuoi = prompt("Bạn hãy nhập vào Tuổi : ", 20);      
document.write("Chào bạn : <B> " + Ten + "</B>");
document.write("<BR>");  // Xuống dòng
document.write("Tuổi của bạn là : <U> " + Tuoi + "</U>");
    //i can paste "Tuổi của bạn là :" but cant type tu?i c?a b?n là
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMzmE.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide steps for others to reproduce the problem (a [mre])? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: select `lesson8.html`, Mouse Right Click, popup menu `Properties` -> `Text` -> `Encoding` , Check the value is ?

Comment: select your project `Demo_PRJ301_SE1702`, mouse Right Click, popup menu `Properties`  , Left Side `Categories` -> `Sources`, Right , Bottom -> Encoding , find the value ?

Comment: @life888888 the encoding is UTF-8 already in both file and project

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual code in your question as many people will not be able to read the pictures of it (including me).

Comment: `I type ư (Vietnamese character) into the console, it starts to convert in to ?`  What is Your question ? (A) is that typing Vietnamese in Console will turn into question marks? (Like Windows Command Line or Linux Terminal ?) (B) or editing html file content in NetBeans and typing Vietnamese will turn into question marks?

Comment: I can't repeat your error, I am use NetBeans 13 in Windows 10, Language setting code page 437 or 950, I can paste `ư` into html file(In Netbeans 13), and It does not convert to `?`.

Comment: Your environment is invalid. NetBeans 13 does not support the use of JDK 8. [From its Release Notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html): _"The Apache NetBeans 13 binary releases **require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17"_. If the problem persists after fixing your environment please raise a new question.

Comment: You are not typing characters into _"the console"_; that is a something else entirely in NetBeans. Based on your screen shot you are typing them into an edit window. What font are you using in that edit window (**Tools > Options > Font & Colors > Font**) , and are you certain that the font you are using supports Vietnamese characters?